# Highcharts - issue about full chart width

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts column chart and I want it to be 100% width responsive chart. The container is a simple `<div>` with no any formatting. When the document loads, the chart is always fixed width 600x400px size. If I resize window or switch to another browser tab, the chart fills the width and becomes responsive full width chart just like I wanted. If I reload page, it's fixed width again. I tried setting width to both container and chart, however, nothing helps. If I move the container div one level above the parent div, It works. How to make the chart become full width on page load also?

Thanks

Comment: please create jsfiddle ?

Comment: Can you show some JavaScript code for the chart and some HTML and CSS of the container? It will be difficult to understand the problem without it.

Comment: As strange as it is, the jsfiddle example I created works fine. I guess it might be a global CSS or something that affects my chart. Anyway, here's the code http://jsfiddle.net/zgsDj/ except that in my real page it is not full width on load, but 600px width.

Comment: Related: [Why are Bootstrap tabs displaying tab-pane divs with incorrect widths when using highcharts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17206631/537554).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Chart's width is taken from `jQuery.width(container)`, so if you have chart in some hidden tabs or something similar, width will be undefined. In that case default width and height are set (600x400).

Comment: "Tabs" was exactly the issue. I was using chart with jQuery UI tabs plugin, and after disabling it, the chart rendered correctly. Now I solved it simply by initializing tabs after the chart has been rendered.

Answer (score 27):

I know this is an old question, but I  ran into the exact same issue and found another solution that works great.

As of Highcharts 4.1.5 (could be in older versions as well), the `chart` object has a `reflow()` function. View the documentation [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.reflow).

> **reflow ()**
>
> Reflows the chart to its container. By default, the chart reflows automatically to its container following a window.resize event, as per the chart.reflow option. However, there are no reliable events for div resize, so if the container is resized without a window resize event, this must be called explicitly.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Simply writing something like $(".tab1").find(".chartContainer").each(function () { $(this).highcharts().reflow()}) inside my $(".button").click() was way more useful than rendering the charts before hiding them. My situation required me to dynamically create charts based on ajax-gets, so this really the best (and only) solution I could find. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect!! Works so well!