# Highcharts container wider than parent div

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

My issue sounds very similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436666/highcharts-issue-about-full-chart-width).

I have 4 highcharts wrapped in a `<div>` inside a `.tab-pane`. Each `.highcharts-container` slightly overextends the width of it's parent. I have attempted to set the width of the chart to 100% but truncates the chart which is not ideal.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tab-pane maxHeight" id="show_graph">
    <div class="row maxHeight maxWide">
        <div class="bottomWrapperTable col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 noPadLeft noPadRight">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="graph_bar_month" class="graph col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
                <div id="graph_bar_teamPercent" class="graph col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
                <div id="graph_line_year" class="graph col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
                <div id="graph_bar_teamActual" class="graph col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Like the issue I have linked to, this error only occurs on page load. For example, I can resize the page and maximise it again and it will be fine. I have attempted to invoke the `reflow()` method to fix this as mentioned in one of the answers in that question. (Used comment and this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/chart-reflow/) to create it)

**jQuery**

```
$('.nav-pills').on('click', function() {
   if($('#show_table').hasClass('active')) {
       $('.bottomWrapperTable').find('.graph').each(function() {
           $(this).highcharts().reflow();
       });
   }
});
```

This solution has not solved it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3eno9pw/) if you look at `graph_bar_month` in devTools, you can see that the highcharts container is wider than it's parent

Comment: Not getting what you saying. Check this: http://i.imgur.com/9WgQGSM.png

Comment: If you expand that `<div>` labelled `#graph_bar_month` and look at the first child within it (has class `.highcharts-container`) and hover over it. The width of that child element exceeds the width of it's parent `#graph_bar_month`

Comment: Check this: [image 1](http://i.imgur.com/jSAg1os.png) & [Image 2](http://i.imgur.com/XNbTMfk.png).

Comment: [images](http://imgur.com/a/lRfVF)

Comment: I tested that in the newest Chrome and not able to recreate that issue, which version do you have? Problem appears also in other browsers?

Comment: Running 46.0.2490.86. Error also appears in IE 11 and Firefox 41.0.2

Comment: For me still works fine, see the screenshot: http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a9o6ly&s=9#.Vk8V3d8vevM

Comment: @SebastianBochan cannot see your image as my proxy blocks it :(

Comment: Has anyone got any other suggestions as to what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had `padding: 0 !important` on `.graph` which caused this error. When I changed my CSS to...

```
.graph {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

...it worked!

**Note:** Do not specify a `height` or `width` on the chart itself, just on it's parent element