# highcharts, mobile responsive, chart not fitting inside container

Tags: javascript, highcharts, responsive

I have a donut chart and a bar chart on a page which is mobile responsive.  On desktop, they are side-by-side.  On mobile, the donut is above the bar chart.  On desktop, the donut sometimes gets cut off to one side.  The element with class highcharts-container defaults to 600px wide.

I have read reflow ([API link](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.reflow)) but it doesn't work in my case.  For example, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16436666/highcharts-issue-about-full-chart-width).

Code samples:

```
  plotOptions: {
    pie: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        distance: -40,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'white',
        }
      },
      startAngle: 0,
      endAngle: 360,
    }
  },


  chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: 0,
    plotShadow: false,
  },
```

Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vaPrNp), but the problem comes and goes.  I've removed irrelevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the `#container` and `#container2` width's in your CSS file, then it should works correct. Here is the code, and example:

```
#container {
  width: 100%
}
#container2 {
  width: 100%
}
```

Live example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBGOgK

Kind regards!